# JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back

Tags: jboss

Hi everyone i am trying to deploy a project in **jboss application server**  and getting the below error but the same .war file uploading successfully in local server so please help me out to resolve this problem .

```
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"xyz.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"xyz.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"xyz.war\""}}}}
```

Comment: Any LIB in your project already present in JBOSS! Are you using primefaces???

Answer (score 1):

It Worked for me.

From below path, take backup of your war files and save in some directory.
JBOSS_UnZip\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments

After that delete all the WAR files and try to deploy your new(fresh)WAR file here(in deployments folder) deployment will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same JDK version that you used for compiling your WAR?